# How to filter an incoming prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a search bar using hooks but the props that I pass into my functional component gives me error and the output is never loaded. I pass the **opt** props from options.js to **Filter.js**. Here's the code:
**Options.js**

```
import Filter from './Filter'
import Option from './Option'

export default (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.handleDeleteOptions}>Remove All</button>
            {props.options.length === 0 && <p>Please add option to get Started!</p>}
            {
                props.options.map((x) => <Option key={x} optionText={x}
                    handleDeleteOption={props.handleDeleteOption}
                />)
            }
            <Filter opt={props.options} />
        </div>
    );

}
```

**Filter.js**

```
export default (props) => {

    const [option, setOption] = React.useState(props);
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("");

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                onChange={e => {
                    const test = props.opt.filter(o => {
                        return o.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
                    });
                    console.log("Option: ", test);

                    setOption(test);
                    setSearch(e.target.value);
                }}
                type="text"
                value={search}
            />
            {props.opt.map(o => (
                <p key={o}>{o}</p>
            ))}


        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: @minsuga: In your Options.js (Parent Component not Option.js) you are receiving the props. RIght? Are you getting them from an API ?

Comment: If you can put all your code on codesandbox and share your link we can have more Idea the the data flow and can help you accordingly :)

Comment: @David I do not get the o/p on browser and in console it shows an empty array. But when I display the props just to check if data is passed or not, it's visible. The filter function doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather yes I send the options array in the form of props from Options.js to Filter.js. It can be easier if I can apply the search bar directly in Options.js but I'm unable to map the logic.

Comment: @minsuga : I would like you to put your code on codesandbox and share the link with me. Sometimes what happens in React is that, Before the data is available the component is rendered and obviously it will scream.. That's why i said share the codesandbox link of this project :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather sure will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you `Filter.js` you are mapping directly the `props.opt`. This doesn't change when you do the filter. What changes is the state. There are two things you need to change for this to work:

- Fix default `option` state: `const [option, setOption] = React.useState(props.opt);`
- Fix the options map. Instead of `props.opt`, use `option` from the state.

Comment: Yes I tried doing that but in Console returns an empty array - Option: [], also nothing is printed on screen.

Comment: It worked out now, but only when I replaced at one place with props.opt with option, if I put in both it doesn't work. Also, it doesn't refreshes the state value